# Writing large data to a excel column cell with looping

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

Parsing .ts file and getting string from that file. i want write that string to excel column. can anyone help me?

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys, xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
doc = minidom.parse("english.ts")


def main():
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    messages = doc.getElementsByTagName("message")
    for message in messages:
        source = message.getElementsByTagName("source")[0]
        ori_string = source.firstChild.data
        print ori_string
        df = pd.DataFrame({'TString': [ori_string]})
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter('new.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
        writer.save()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not getting error and "ori_string" is printing but in excel sheet nothing is written.

I want to just write the string to the excel column.how to iterate  rows and how to give row and column number inside iteration?

Comment: You are overwriting the xlsx file with each iteration through the `for` loop. Either build a Pandas dataframe in the loop and write the xlsx file outside the loop or just omit Pandas and use XlsxWriter directly by creating the workbook and worksheet outside the loop and writing the data inside the loop.

Comment: thank you for reply. i tried with xlsxWriter but in that also i am getting error like AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'write'. can you tell me how to pass that string to the dataFrame?(outside loop or inside loop? because in every iteration one string is coming so i want to write that string to each cell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import sys, xlsxwriter

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
doc = minidom.parse("english.ts")


def main():
    row = 0
    messages = doc.getElementsByTagName("message")
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data3.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    for message in messages:
        source = message.getElementsByTagName("source")[0]
        ori_string = source.firstChild.data
        print ori_string
        worksheet.write(row, 0, ori_string)
        row += 1    
    workbook.close()
```

> Now its working thank you @DavidG for your suggestion.